# Different error on native compiler vs web compiler

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors

I'm having a strange issue, and being new to c++ isn't helping. I wrote the following to make a simple 2D matrix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::vector<int> > grid(){
     std::vector< std::vector<int> > vect;
     vect = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
     return vect;
}
```

When I run this on a site like [cpp.sh](https://cpp.sh), it works perfectly fine, but when I use g++ on my macbook, I get the following error:

```
username % g++ main.cpp 
main.cpp:6:13: error: expected expression
     vect = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
            ^
1 error generated.
```

I've updated my gcc, and I've run with both g++ and gcc – both have the same issue. I installed gcc with homebrew and i've just been running `g++ main.cpp` and then executing `a.out`.

Note: I'm on MacOS Monterey on M1

Comment: what version of gcc is it ?

Comment: the code requires C++11, which is default with gcc since 6 I believe. Error with gcc5: https://godbolt.org/z/Me35zqTq6

Comment: i didnt find any gcc version that produces the same error. Please include the complete error message

Comment: From VSCode questions I expect that you are using clang (gcc could be symlinked) and the default settings are c++98 for the version installed requiring you to have to set the std version from the command line: `-std=c++17`

Comment: By default, `g++` on MacOS is actually an alias to Apple Clang, which still seems to default to C++98.

Comment: You need to compile with `clang++ -std=c++11` (or higher, on Monterey you can go use `c++11`, `c++14`, `c++17`, `c++20`) on macos for this code.

Comment: How do you compile your code? Which command/IDE do you use? Please include this information in your question

Comment: IMHO, you should pass the 2d vector by reference to eliminate a lot of copying.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments! For anyone else having similar issues:

On macOS Monterey `gcc/g++` (by default) uses the 1998 version, where my code requires the 2011+ versions.

To compile with the newer version, @wlk showed that I could use `clang++ -std=c++11` to specify the version.

By adding `alias g++="clang++ -std=c++20"` to my `.zshrc` file, I can run g++ with the 2020 version – without issue.